# Como validar las entradas de fechas con datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker, calendario

tengo un modal donde estoy colocando dos datetimepicker uno para ingresar una fecha inicial y el otro una fecha final, con el objetivo de buscar en la bd ciertos datos que estén entre estas dos fechas, he estado buscando pero no he logrado encontrar las instrucciones para validar que si ya ingrese una fecha inicial, evite que en el segundo datetimepicker pueda seleccionar una fecha anterior, es decir que si ingreso 01/02/2022 (2022/02/01) no me permita seleccionar 31/01/2022(2022/01/31) ni ninguna otra fecha anterior a la señalada en el primero.

Estoy utilizando boostrap-datetimepicker para este evento.

Mi código de los datetimepicker:

```js
                                                               $("#reporteCategoriaA1").datetimepicker({
 language: 'es',
 startDate:new Date(),
 format: "YYYY-MM-DD",  // Solo se ocupa la fecha
 yearRange:"-99:+0", // no hace nada
 maxDate: "+0m +0d", // no hace nada
 //format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", // no se requiere la hora
 timepicker:false,
 autoclose: true,
 //pickTime: false
 showButtonPanel: true,
 });
 
$("#reporteCategoriaA2").datetimepicker({
 language: 'es',
 startDate:new Date(),
 format: "YYYY-MM-DD",  // Solo se ocupa la fecha
 yearRange:"-99:+0", // no hace nada
 maxDate: "+0m +0d", // no hace nada
 //format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", // no se requiere la hora
 timepicker:false,
 autoclose: true,
 //pickTime: false
 showButtonPanel: true,
 });
```

Agradezco cualquier aporte.

Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución es simple. Suponiendo que estás usando [jquery-datetimepicker](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) (lo cual nunca especificas), usa el evento `onChangeDateTime` para detectar cuando se establece una fecha en el primer `datetimepicker`. Dentro de la función que maneja el evento, establece la fecha mínima (`minDate`) del segundo `datetimepicker` a la fecha que seleccionó el usuario en el primero.

Te adjunto un ejemplo que puede probar desde acá:

```js
function handleChange(e){
   $("#reporteCategoriaA2").datetimepicker({
       minDate: new Date(e)
    })
}


$("#reporteCategoriaA1").datetimepicker({
 language: 'es',
 startDate:new Date(),
 format: "Y-m-d",  // Solo se ocupa la fecha
 yearRange:"-99:+0", // no hace nada
 maxDate: "+0m +0d", // no hace nada
 //format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", // no se requiere la hora
 timepicker:false,
 autoclose: true,
 //pickTime: false
 showButtonPanel: true,
 onChangeDateTime: handleChange
 });
 
$("#reporteCategoriaA2").datetimepicker({
 language: 'es',
 startDate:new Date(),
 format: "Y-m-d",  // Solo se ocupa la fecha
 yearRange:"-99:+0", // no hace nada
 maxDate: "+0m +0d", // no hace nada
 //format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss", // no se requiere la hora
 timepicker:false,
 autoclose: true,
 //pickTime: false
 showButtonPanel: true,
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" id="reporteCategoriaA1">
<input type="text" id="reporteCategoriaA2">
```

---

Usando boostrap-datetimepicker

```js
$("#reporteCategoriaA1").datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'

});

$("#reporteCategoriaA2").datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
});

$("#reporteCategoriaA1").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('#reporteCategoriaA2').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
});

$("#reporteCategoriaA2").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    $('#reporteCategoriaA1').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/moment.js/2.18.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="startTime" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha inicial: </label>
  <div class="col-sm-10 input-group date" id="startTimePicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reporteCategoriaA1" placeholder="Introduzca la hora de inicio">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group">
  <label for="startTime" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha final: </label>
  <div class="col-sm-10 input-group date" id="startTimePicker">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reporteCategoriaA2" placeholder="Introduzca la hora de inicio">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, aquí funciona a la perfección, déjame probar en mi desarrollo y cualquier detalle te comento.  Buen día!!.

Comment: Una última que me surgió mientras elaboraba la respuesta. ¿Estás usando `jquety-datetimepicker` o `bootstrap-datetimepicker`?

Comment: bootstrap-datetimepicker , por lo que estoy viendo no me va a funcionar adecuadamente ya que en el ejemplo estas utilizando jquery.datetimepicker.full.js, quizás deba cambiar mis librerias....

Comment: Buff, deberías especificar eso en tu pregunta. No estoy seguro que te sirva mi respuesta. Son muy similares pero no son iguales. Me haces saber.

Comment: Pues seria cuestión de probar, que la parte de la vista utilizar las css de boostrap, y la parte que corresponde ya al datetimepicker, cambiar a las jquery que indicas en el ejemplo y probar.  Por que efectivamente no hace nada sigue haciendo lo mismo que antes de añadir esas lineas.

Comment: Pues pequeños detalles,  añadí el css y los js del ejemplo que explicas, y bueno si cambia totalmente la vista ya no es al estilo boostrap, ahora el detalle es que en el input no me muestra la fecha que se selecciona, por lo demás funciona tal cual como lo señalas en el ejemplo.  Si valida que no se pueda seleccionar fechas anteriores a la indicada primeramente.  Asi como tampoco permite seleccionar una fecha posterior al dia de hoy, eso esta excelente.

Comment: Te acabo de adjuntar un ejemplo con bootstrap-datetimepicker. Por alguna razón, el código de configuración que adjuntas no me funciona y me dice que hay cosas que están deprecated. Te adjunté un ejemplo mínimo funcional.

Comment: Gracias ya lo probé aquí y funciona perfectamente,  ahora tengo que actualizar todas mis librerías por lo que mencionas por que efectivamente algo sucedió que ahora resulta que me indica que no es posible utilizar minDate y maxDate, encontré un ejemplo donde venían estos eventos y me dice que no son funciones.

Comment: Antes de actualizar siéntate y analiza bien tus dependencias. Investigando para esta pregunta resulta que hay un MONTÓN de librerías parecidas: `bootstrap-datepicker.js`, `bootstrap-datetimepicker`, el `date-picker` formateado nativo de bootstrap,  `jquery-datetimepicker` y montón más. Mi consejo es, céntrate en una, busca la documentación, intenta hacerlo con esa específica que seleccionaste, y luego, si te trabas, entonces creas una pregunta especificando claramente la librería  que utilizas con su documentación para que recibas respuestas específicas. En esta pregunta te olvidaste de ello.

Comment: incluso existe la posibilidad de que solo se utilice de manera nativa en el input  utilizando el type="time" pero quería que se viera un poco mas elegante.  En base a tu ultima aportación,  lo único que puedo ver que es diferente y por estar mas actualizadas son las versiones de las librerías empezando por jquery y las boostrap,  las que yo tengo ya son muy viejas , para boostrap tengo la version 3.0.0 y de jquery estaba utilizando la 1.12.3  antes me funciona.  Gracias por tu aporte y el consejo. Lo checo bendiciones!!!

Comment: ya me funciona, hice un mezcla entre bootstrap y el primer ejemplo que me pusiste, esto derivado de un error en la vista que por mas que revise, cambie los js y los css nada mas no queda.   Al final tengo los componentes boostrap aunque el calendario es jquery y funciona bien sin problema.  Te agradezco la atencion. Buen fin!!!! y semana de vacaciones si eres de México

Comment: Genial! Al final bootstrap y jquery se integran muy bien y usan estilos muy similares. Estoy seguro que todo se integra muy bien. Me alegra lo hayas resuelto. Buen fin para ti también!

Answer (score 0):

Después de continuar revisando y actualizando el proyecto, al incorporar elementos nuevos sobre un desarrollo antiguo.

respecto al datetimepicker termine descargando las librerías para el calendario de este sitio [datetimepicker 2.5.20](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/).

Para que me muestre el idioma en español tuve que descargar librerías adicionales, descargue `moment.js` y una carpeta denominada locale que contiene un diccionario muy extenso de idiomas.

y añadir unas lineas adicionales de código por fuera de la función del datetimepicker para que tomara el idioma.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery.datetimepicker.setLocale('es');
        });
```

ya que la petición interna `language: 'es'` & `locale: 'es'`  ninguna de estas funcionaba.

Seguí utilizando las librerías de bootstrap (version v3.3.7) para los botones y vistas en general como el modal etc, y la libreria jquery 3.5.1 para uso general.

Por si a alguien le sirve esta experiencia.

Saludos